# If the “bold” property is set to “true,” the text should be displayed in bold

Tags: reactjs

I am looking for help converting a property from a string to a Boolean before page is rendered.  The bold property is going to be either set as a string of 'true' or 'false'.   I have set the state of the property but the string 'false' is still true.  I am currently trying to convert to Boolean in my handleClick function but I need to convert if before the page is rendered.

HTML

```
<script type="text/jsx">

ReactDOM.render(
 <div>
 <FontChooser min='4' max='40' size='16' text='Fun with React!' bold='true'/>
</div>, document.getElementById('container'));

</script>
```

JS

```
class FontChooser extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {hidden: 'true', size: this.props.size, bold: this.props.bold, min : this.props.min, max: this.props.max, color: 'black'}; 

}


handleClick() {
    if(this.state.hidden == 'true') {
        if(this.props.bold == "true") {
            this.setState({bold: true}) 
        } else {
            this.setState({bold: false})
        }

        this.setState({hidden: ''});

    }
    else {
        this.setState({hidden: 'true'});    
    }           
}

decrease() {
    if (this.state.size >= Number(this.state.min) +1) 
    this.setState({size: Number(this.state.size) -1});

    if(this.state.size == Number(this.state.min) +1|| this.state.size == Number(this.state.min)) {
        this.setState({color: 'red'})
    } else {
        this.setState({color: 'black'})
    }
}

increase() {
    if (this.state.size <= Number(this.state.max) -1)       
    this.setState({size: Number(this.state.size) +1});  

    if(this.state.size == Number(this.state.max) -1|| this.state.size == Number(this.state.max)) {
        this.setState({color: 'red'})
    } else {
        this.setState({color: 'black'})
    }


}

toggle() {
    this.setState({bold: !this.state.bold});
}





render() {

    var weight = this.state.bold ? 'bold' : 'normal';       
    var checked = this.state.bold ? 'true' : '';

    var inlineStyle = {
        fontSize: this.state.size,
        fontWeight: weight,         
    };

    var fontSizeSpanStyle = {
        color: this.state.color
    }





return(

       <div>
       <input type="checkbox" id="boldCheckbox" checked={checked} hidden={this.state.hidden}onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)} />
       <button id="decreaseButton" hidden={this.state.hidden} onClick={this.decrease.bind(this)} >-</button>
       <span id="fontSizeSpan" hidden={this.state.hidden} style={fontSizeSpanStyle} >{this.state.size}</span>
       <button id="increaseButton" hidden={this.state.hidden} onClick={this.increase.bind(this)} >+</button>
       <span id="textSpan" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} style={inlineStyle} >{this.props.text}
       </span>       
       </div>
);
}
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason not to just use a boolean?

Comment: this is a homework assignment and has an auto grader that has values already set as strings.

Comment: If props are strings, keep them as booleans inside. Currently you are using both booleans and strings in your state, e.g. `bold: this.props.bold` uses a string and `this.setState({bold: true}) ` uses a boolean. That means you won't be able to use plain `!this.state.bold` but you will have to use `this.state == 'false'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting bold as string from props but you can just change it directly when you initially set the component state

So while setting the `bold` state you just convert it to boolean

```
bold: (this.props.bold == "true" ? true : false)
```

I also have one more comment you should avoid accessing props from constructor you should access props in componentWillMount function

Check the code below with applied changes:

```
class FontChooser extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props);
   this.state = {};
}

componentWillMount(){
    this.setState({hidden: 'true', size: this.props.size, bold: (this.props.bold == "true" ? true : false) , min : this.props.min, max: this.props.max, color: 'black'}); 
}


handleClick() {
    if(this.state.hidden == 'true') {
        if(this.props.bold == "true") {
            this.setState({bold: true}) 
        } else {
            this.setState({bold: false})
        }

        this.setState({hidden: ''});

    }
    else {
        this.setState({hidden: 'true'});    
    }           
}

decrease() {
    if (this.state.size >= Number(this.state.min) +1) 
    this.setState({size: Number(this.state.size) -1});

    if(this.state.size == Number(this.state.min) +1|| this.state.size == Number(this.state.min)) {
        this.setState({color: 'red'})
    } else {
        this.setState({color: 'black'})
    }
}

increase() {
    if (this.state.size <= Number(this.state.max) -1)       
    this.setState({size: Number(this.state.size) +1});  

    if(this.state.size == Number(this.state.max) -1|| this.state.size == Number(this.state.max)) {
        this.setState({color: 'red'})
    } else {
        this.setState({color: 'black'})
    }


}

toggle() {
    this.setState({bold: !this.state.bold});
}





render() {

    var weight = this.state.bold ? 'bold' : 'normal';       
    var checked = this.state.bold ? 'true' : '';

    var inlineStyle = {
        fontSize: this.state.size,
        fontWeight: weight,         
    };

    var fontSizeSpanStyle = {
        color: this.state.color
    }





return(

       <div>
       <input type="checkbox" id="boldCheckbox" checked={checked} hidden={this.state.hidden}onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)} />
       <button id="decreaseButton" hidden={this.state.hidden} onClick={this.decrease.bind(this)} >-</button>
       <span id="fontSizeSpan" hidden={this.state.hidden} style={fontSizeSpanStyle} >{this.state.size}</span>
       <button id="increaseButton" hidden={this.state.hidden} onClick={this.increase.bind(this)} >+</button>
       <span id="textSpan" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} style={inlineStyle} >{this.props.text}
       </span>       
       </div>
);}
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I think this will help me.  I did not know I could use if/else when setting the state.

Comment: It's actually desired to use the `props` in `constructor` to set the initial `state` and *not* in `componentDidMount` because that will create an additional rendering.

Comment: You're right i updated the code to use props in ```componentWillMount``` ... not ```ComponentDidMount```  ... now we don't have additional rendering and we avoid accessing props in constructor ... thanks for the comment Sulthan

Comment: @AmrLabib Well, using `constructor` would be easier. That's why `props` are passed there.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want (or have) to work with string values, maybe the easiest way to handle that is by:

```
constructor() {
  this.state = {
    ...
    bold: this.props.bold === 'true',
  }
}
```

and then on each `bold` change:

```
this.setState({
  bold: !this.state.bold,
})
```

I strongly recommend using such properties (bold, hidden...) as boolean props.